# What are the moving particles that can be seen by the Parker Solar Probe?

Tags: probe, venus, materials, the-sun, parker-solar-probe

There ate two images below from the Parker Probe, one of Venus and the second from the Sun. The second one is a screenshot from a recent video ([Youtube of Parker imagery while in solar corona](https://youtu.be/S3I30ZzsIKU)).

In both you can see particles of some sort. What are they?

An image of Venus taken on July 11, 2020, by an instrument on NASA's Parker Solar Probe.

[image: An image of Venus taken on July 11, 2020, by an instrument on NASA's Parker Solar Probe]

Screenshot from the video from the Parker probe looking at the Milky Way when  the Parker probe did a flyby at the sun, updated for clarity.
[image]

Original poster's screenshot
[image: Original poster's screenshot]

Comment: That's on a very sensitive exposure (enough to actually show the milky way, which is impressive for any imager, much less one inside the sun's corona) , so the lightsources are very faint. Possibly just outgassing from Parker's heatshield, shining in the sunlight?

Comment: Guessing it's stuff ablating off the heatshield

Comment: @AntonHengst I surely hope not, as it was present while passing Venus, and that is less than 1/80th the maximum heat load.

Comment: @Kitty the ablation is caused by hypervelocity impacts from interplanetary dust, not by heat.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[According to NASA:](https://www.nasa.gov/feature/goddard/2021/parker-solar-probe-offers-a-stunning-view-of-venus)

> Bright streaks in WISPR, such as the ones seen here, are typically
> caused by a combination of charged particles — called cosmic rays —
> sunlight reflected by grains of space dust, and particles of material
> expelled from the spacecraft’s structures after impact with those dust
> grains. The number of streaks varies along the orbit or when the
> spacecraft is traveling at different speeds, and scientists are still
> in discussion about the specific origins of the streaks here. The dark
> spot appearing on the lower portion of Venus is an artifact from the
> WISPR instrument.

To clarify the NASA statement, **cosmic rays** directly impact the detector and generate electrons to produce bright pixels in the image, leaving linear features as the charged particles traverse the detector material. **Dust** and **ablated spacecraft material** are flying around in space and reflecting sunlight, appearing as linear features due to their velocity relative to the spacecraft.

Comment: and especially [How did Parker Solar Probe take what looks like 2D cross-sections of the solar wind in photographs; high contrast streaks in focus from volume effect?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/47814/7982) whose answer is complementary to yours.

Comment: great answer dave, +1, and i added an explanation because NASA's em-dashes make it a little unclear that bright features in the image are produced in very different ways by CRs and dust/ablated material.

Comment: @uhoh Why are you promoting your own questions on other not related questions? Do you have a popularity problem?

Comment: @KingsInnerSoul you can also flag my comments for deletion, applicable reasons include "no longer needed" and "other" followed by an explanation. I think that moderators are less likely to remove comments that have several upvotes (as mine do) indicating that others have found the comments helpful/valuable, but it's certainly another option.